# How to use DSASignatureFormatter in C# to verify the signature

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

This might not be a very clear question since I'm new to **crypto** algorithm. Please help me improve it.

Here's the problem I met.

I got a key pair (**DS128**) like followings:

> private key: a8a5ea3b0249e822731133f52d24b29d152a0c05
>
> public key: 91053fd2f09ec4fbfeb9713245855b7dcd33906a7f7d5bedf28e3f39ce6641e4de956ad81206874f2a8647596bb9004ef8b9021f5a519291e417f6a86064e976f845b59990c1efbd2a13f2dd12221d6bc82f7c39acfbbbd46a1f56a10930162630d76700f1d4b1b501d378986aa0614efafb91c12f1c34939a2f92b6e4248803

More, I have the signature in **JWT** format:

> eyJhbGciOiJEUzEyOCJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzNDM3MDQxNDQyMDgsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGV2ZWxvcGVyLm1vemlsbGEub3JnIn0.ozqgmide0XtMKkT2Gp3DcVD3Fr3RaL031O9F_zgMfRB_olekSQTcXw

What I knew is the algorithm is **DSA128** which can be obtained by decoding the header (the string before the first ".") of the sign. Additionally, the middle part is the data signed on and the last part is the sign.

My question is, does anyone know that how to use the **.net crypto** class ***DSASignatureFormatter*** to verify the signature mentioned above?

The main issue is that, I don't know how to use the public key. It seems that some transformation on the public key should be conducted before I can send it to the verification function provided by ***DSASignatureFormatter***...